# Which cases save data in savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458065/restarting-activity-creates-duplicate-fragments), and the answer I got was related to the status of savedInstanceState. I would like to know in which cases information is saved in savedInstanceState, also for what other purpose does the OS uses the savedInstanceState. I've found some info which relates savedInstanceState with Android lifecycle, but I can't understand exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever an Activity is killed for resources or restarted due to configuration changes, onSaveInstanceState is called.  This includes when a background Activity is terminated.

If an Activity is killed for normal reasons (like by calling finish) or terminated due to crash/ANR/force stopped then it isn't.

Comment: Does using split screen count as configuration changes?

Comment: It should, thats a screen size change.  Anything that changes this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration datastructure should  (note that the keyboard in that structure is a hardware keyboard, not a software one.  So opening up the soft keyboard does not, but sliding out an old school slide away keyboard would).